# My i know MySQL Query for this?

Tags: mysql, sql

My i know for MysQL query for this?

it can be in 1 sql statement or 2 sql statement?

```
Table1

id    main    rate
1     10      3                       |  10 * 3   =   30
                                              total = 30

table2

id    table1_id    value   newnum
1         1          20      3         |  20 * 3   =   60 
2         1          30      2         |  30 * 2   =   60
3         1          22      3         |  22 * 3   =   66
4         1          0       0
                                       total = 186

Result

table1_result        table2_result        final
30                     186                216
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try something . And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please read & act on [ask] & [mcve] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. PS MySQL outputs per a certain format. Your output isn't in that format. So what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear if you will only ever have one row, or if you could have multiple rows of output but this should help either way:

```
select id, main*rate t1.table1_result, t2.table2_result
from table_1 t1
inner join (
      select table1_id, sum(value * newnum) table2_result
      from table_2
      group by table1_id    
      ) t2 on t1.id = t2.t1id
-- optional
where t1.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to calculate sum of individual tables in individual queries using group by and then joining the result in main query as below.

```
SELECT table1_result,
       table2_result,
       table1_result + table2_result AS FINAL
FROM
  (SELECT id,
          sum(main*rate) AS table1_result
   FROM table1 t1
   GROUP BY id) AS t1
JOIN
  (SELECT table1_id,
          sum(value*newnum) AS table2_result
   FROM table2 t2
   GROUP BY table1_id ) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.table1_id
```

**Result:**

```
+---------------+---------------+-------+
| table1_result | table2_result | final |
+---------------+---------------+-------+
|            30 |           186 |   216 |
+---------------+---------------+-------+
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/GJAHB65816)**